# Allow Hyphen with word between two double quote regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

i have created on regular expression to catch word between double quote. 
example

```
string = Hi[pause="x-weak"]Parth[pause="weak"]How[pause="medium"]are[pause="strong"]You[pause="x-strong"]tell me

regex = \[\h*pause\h*=\h*"\h*(\w+)\h*"\h*]
```

It's matching `[pause="weak"]` only. I need it to match all tags with `pause`.

Comment: You may use `preg_match_all('~\[\h*pause\h*=\h*"\h*(.*?)\h*"\h*]~', $s, $matches)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\[[^][]*pause="(?P<type>[^"]+)"
```

which would also catch the `type`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gpLtiO/1/).

---

In `PHP` this could be

```
<?php

$string = 'Hi[pause="x-weak"]Parth[pause="weak"]How[pause="medium"]are[pause="strong"]You[pause="x-strong"]tell me';
$regex = '~\[[^][]*pause="(?P<type>[^"]+)"~';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/XZMx4A).